# Need help in writing Guitar Solos using story

Tags: guitar, songwriting, solos

I heard lot from online videos(Literally all) that the key thing to awesome solo is - Story. But I am kinda confused that how one implements this? Please share how you implement the "Story" strategy of you writing solos or thinking process? Thank you.

PS: I particularly like melodic shred solos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are referring to is the use of a narrative in a solo, which applies to any instrument and any music genre, if you want to connect to your listener and make something musical.

This mostly means that you play something with intention and control, instead of random. When you tell a story, a listener understands what is happening, can predict where it is going to go (enough predictability to keep one connected and enough unpredictability to keep interest!), understands where the climax of the story is, and understands when the story is over, without you having to tell this things specifically to the listener. Knowing how to build tension and how to release it is something all music professionals know how to do in very different and subtle ways.

As an example, a very simple story or narrative is just building tension, reaching a climax, and then releasing tension. For this you should start at a low level of intensity (solos that already start shredding at the highest intensity level are in danger of becoming stale and musically uninteresting - although it can be fun too, so no harm, as long as it is intentional), know how long the solo should last, and accordingly, know where to place the climax, or highest point of intensity/tension. This can be achieved by a lot of different ways: Tension by dynamics (soft to loud), tension by use of harmonic (consonance to dissonance), tension by use of rhythmic dynamics (slow to fast), use of sound textures (specially useful in non acoustic instruments like electric guitar and use of effects), use of repetition to reinforce segments and create expectation, etc. And then back to release by inverting that.

Of course this is just one simple example. You can find other ways of narrating your story. Maybe you do start high, then go low, play around with that. If you do this right, not only the audience will be engaged, but the band you play with will understand you and will be able to follow you, playing with your 'story'.

The ways you find of doing this depend on your technical ability on the instrument, intellectual understanding of music theory, and emotional ability to play around with expectations, use or avoidance of cliches, etc.

This is my understanding on the need of a "story" in a solo, or artistic composition in general. Hope it helps a bit

Answer (score 3):

Can I throw you one right out of left field - you'll hate the songs. I don't care ;-)

Rather than 'shred' listen to the masterpieces of pop solo.

Getting a solo worthy of remembering in a simple 3-minute pop song form is a structure so infrequently done well that it's a pure art-form in itself & the members of that club are in rarified air.

Start with The Carpenters 'Goodbye to Love' followed by Nik Kershaw's 'Wouldn't it be Good' then The Commodores 'Easy'.
I chose all three of these because though they're well-played, they are not reliant on technique, they are absolutely reliant on story.

They're not going to teach you how to write 'story' in a more complex field, but they'll give you some simple clues as to what 'story' is made of in the first place. It echoes the rest of the song, yet adds elements you couldn't have used in the broader song melody. It can start simple & build complexity… it draws you through, it cannot be boring.

BTW, in case you don't want to listen to the whole thing - though I think you should - the Goodbye to Love solo reprises after the last choruses right to the fade & is well worth the wait.
You must listen to the entirety of these songs to understand the place the solo has in each - they all serve different purposes. I didn't pick them at random ;)